# POST request parameters returning "none"

Tags: flask, post, python-requests

I have the following POST request:

```
import requests

payload = {'key1':'value1'}
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test', params=payload)
print(r.url)
print(r.text)
```

My flask app tries to return the value from key1:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def query_params():
    val = request.args.get("key1")
    return val
```

Going to http://127.0.0.1:5000/test returns

> TypeError TypeError: The view function for 'query_params' did not
> return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended
> without a return statement.

Output from flask debugger:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2022 21:47:17] "POST /test?key1=value1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

What am I missing here? Thank you very much for your help!

Cheers,
Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you visit the `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test` from your browser, its a GET request and there are no parameters passed in your request.

if you visit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test?key1=value1`, your expected output will be printed.

Regarding the `requests.post` snippet you used: if you see the [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post), `params` is usually used in GET requests, the POSTS get the `data` argument. but seems your code works, it appends the parameters to the request (as would have happened in GET) and makes a POST request. Interesting finding!

```
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/test', data=payload)
```

you could enhance your code by using a "fallback" value if the parameter is not present:

```
@app.route('/test', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def query_params():
    val = request.args.get("key1", "parameter was not provided")
    return val
```

To conclude, i think you should decide if the request method to submit the data should be a GET or a POST, and then update your code accordingly (if GET, your snippets is OK, if you should use POST, try to switch the `params` to `data` and then your flask route code to work with the new payload "format".

**updated code** to "launch a python script if the flask app receives a POST request with a specific key:value pair":

```
@app.route('/test', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def query_params():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        val = request.args.get("the expected key", "parameter was not provided")
        if val == "the expected value":
            # do the things you want to do
            return "processing done!"
```

Comment: Thank you @ilias-sp,
I made the suggested edits and after sending the post request the terminal returns '''value1''' but going to '''http://127.0.0.1:8000/test''' still returns "parmeter was not provided". I guess the problem is that I manually visit ''http://127.0.0.1:8000/test''' after sending the post request. Since POST requests are not stored I would need to store the '''value1''' in the flask script, right?

Comment: the GET request from the browser is different/not related to the POST you made from the `requests` script. you can see from the URL that it doesnt contain any info/parameters, just access the webserver `127.0.0.1:8000` at path: `/test`. If you want to pass parameters using GET, you would have to pass them after the `/test` path, for example: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/test?key1=value&param2=value2'.

Comment: Thanks to you I understood now the difference between the post request from my script and the browser request! The real aim of my script is to launch a python script if the flask app receives a POST request with a specific key:value pair. How would I do that?

Comment: please see updated answer. You did say "launch a python script" but i would try to "copy" the python script into the flask route for a better integration. If you insist on launching a python script instead, you should look into using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) python module to spawn a new OS process that will fire your python script.

Comment: Thank you very much @ilias-sp for putting me on the right track! Cheers!

Comment: i am glad i was of help! @MarioKreutzfeldt